# Equation Labeling and Referencing

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have different equations in different sections / Appendix while writing my thesis. I am already using `amsmath` package and used the `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` in preamble. However, while I label equations as they occur in the section, e.g. In Section 1 the first equation is labelled as `{eq:1}` and In Appendix A, the first equation is labeled as `{eq:1}` as well.

When compiling, the equations are correctly labeled in the `.pdf` document, but I receive errors of multiple labeling. It is not easy to change equations in the main text of thesis and keep changing the labeling in Appendix as well.

I have tried finding this query but not successful. Can someone point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do not use numerical labels, use *describing* values like `archimedes` or `einstein` or   `wombat` .

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=29974&p=101270#p101269)

Comment: Using the same label name is always a logical error. And what Johannes_B said, so use `\label{app:eq:foo}` etc.

Comment: In the comment above, the `app:` would describe the appendix, `eq:` an equation and `foo` what the equation is actually about. This is for you as a human being to remember nicely. (La)TeX doesn't care, it would be happy if the label is set to `iuyidye74hcnd720wjcgdye` (but only once). For a human, this is very hard to remember.

Comment: You could use `\label{app:1}` for Appendix.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just changed the conventional referencing and resorted to section wise/topic-wise labeling. Works great. Appreciate your feedback. Cheers

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you want to answer?

Comment: @juanuni Use of numbers is a bad idea, as noted above.

Comment: @cfr Don't we have a duplicate somewhere?

Comment: @Johannes_B Probably. In fact, surely. Can we find it, though?

Comment: @cfr I'll have a loik later today.

Comment: Yes is bad idea, but maybe he have an order with numbers for his equations ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of "multiply defined" label warning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126309/how-to-get-rid-of-multiply-defined-label-warning)